# What values can take expression

Tags: functional-equations

What values can take the expression
 $T=\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{f(t^2)+f(t)-2f(0)+2}\mspace{20mu},\mspace{15mu}  $ where

$f(2x+y)-f(x+y)=2x , \mspace{20mu}x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

No idea what to do

Comment: Try $y = -x$ in the functional equation...

Answer (score 1):

When one substitutes the value $y= -x$ in the functional equation $f(2x+y)-f(x+y)=2x$ you get $f(x)-f(0)=2x$.  So you instantly know that in
$$T=\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{f(t^2)+f(t)-2f(0)+2}$$
the numerator $f(t)-f(0)$ must equal $2t$.  And the denominator, $$f(t^2)+f(t)-2f(0)+2=(f(t^2)-f(0))+f(t)-f(0)+2$$ must reduce to $2t^2 + 2t+2$, so your fraction becomes $$T=\frac{2t}{2t^2+2t+2} = \frac t{t^2+t+1}.$$